# How can I getting textarea value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make submit event depend textarea value. cause i want to check textarea is vaild. so when I was using javascript function getElementByid, it result was placeholder value.

I just want to know how can I fix it.

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="input">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="<?php _e("Your Comment Here", "bonestheme"); ?>" tabindex="4" style="border:1px solid #cbcbcb; resize:none"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <input class="btn-commnet" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="<?php _e("Submit Comment","bonestheme"); ?>" />
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Where is your javascript code.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `.value`. Here's a demo:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('test');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function updateResult() {
    result.textContent = textarea.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', updateResult);
```

```html
<textarea id="test" placeholder="Some placeholder"></textarea>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

A little unclear as to what you need to do but if you just want to validate that the textarea value is something other then the placeholder text, you could add a handler to call on click of the button, something like:

```
<input class="btn-commnet" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="<?php _e("Submit Comment","bonestheme"); ?>" onclick="return ValidationEvent()"/>
```

then have a javascript function that checks the value prior to submitting..

```
function ValidationEvent() {
    commentElm = document.getElementById('comment');
    if(commentElm.value === commentElm.placeholder)
        return false;   
    return true;
}
```

This could be greatly simplified using Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Try below example. It's very easy. It doesn't return placeholder value it returns content that is written in textarea either you write static or dynamic. I just specify how to get simply textarea value instead of placeholder. If you want to set any validation then show me your java script code, so that i can give you better result.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc()
{
  var getTextArea = document.getElementById("txtArea");
  var value = getTextArea.value;
  alert(value);//It will show you text area value
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txtArea" placeholder="hello">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" onclick="abc()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same great sample as the upvoted answer but I added a replacement of the `\n` with `<br/>`

Now if you hit enter at the end of each line you'll see something like:
[image: sample code takes care of line breaks]

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('test');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function updateResult() {
    let changedText = replaceAllReturns(textarea.value);
    result.innerHTML = changedText;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', updateResult);

function replaceAllReturns(inText){
    let outText = inText;
    while(outText.indexOf("\n") >=0){
      outText = outText.replace("\n","<br/>");
    }
    return outText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test" placeholder="Some placeholder"></textarea>
<p id="result"></p>
```