# On button click sending the whole <textarea></textarea>

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling to send only the content in the text area not the whole header

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter your message" id="message"></textarea>
    <button onclick="sendMsg(message)"> Submit </button>
```

And it's not sending the content in the text area it's sending the whole thing

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter your message" id="message"></textarea>
```

That's the function it's not done yet but the console log is returning that.

```
function sendMsg(msg) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log(msg);

    }
```

Thanks a ton guys

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What do you mean by "header"? How are you determining it is sending this header? You should provide a [mcve] and include [debugging details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: I did console.log(message) and it gives me <textarea placeholder="Enter your message" id="message"></textarea>

Comment: Please show `sendMsg` function

Comment: Im editing it to add the send Msg function. Give me 30 sec

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078349/how-can-i-getting-textarea-value-using-javascript

Comment: That's not solved either

Comment: @Maths101 — If you mean "There is no accepted answer on that question" then you're right, but it doesn't stop it being a duplicate of your question or the answers there solving your problem.

Comment: @Maths101 sometimes the original asker never accepts an answer. That doesn't mean existing answers aren't correct. Try them first. If they didn't work for you, explain that here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the `element`,
you need the value of the element, so try

```
console.log(msg.value)
```

Comment: Yes that's the correct answer thank you ! I will accept it in 7 minutes